# XSLT Sort converts CDATA to Normal XML Text

Tags: xml, xslt, cdata

I am using the following XSLT on my XML for sorting

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[*]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates>
                <xsl:sort select="local-name()"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Handling|Handling//*" priority="2">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

The issue here is that all Character Data in my resulting XML is converted to normal text, which is difficult for my SAX parser, as the data has a lot of special characters and HTML tags. Is there a way I can avoid conversion of CDATA into text?

For Example :

```
<description><![CDATA[Never program while driving.<p>]]></description>
```

Is converted to

```
<description>Never program while driving.&lt;p&gt;</description>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `xsl:output` element takes `cdata-section-elements` attribute you would need to set to a space separated list of element names like `description` whose content you want to have serialized as CDATA sections.

`<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" cdata-section-elements="description"/>`

Comment: Well description is one of the tags. I have multiple tags with CDATA and I want all of them to be preserved. Any way I can do that?

Comment: @BrownTownCoder Yes, a "space separated list" of those elements as the value of the `cdata-section-elements` attribute of the `xsl:output` element. I am just repeating what Martin said though.

Comment: With pure XSLT, you would need to know the names of those elements when writing the stylesheet and list them all in the `xsl:output`.